# Why is my Ajax passing "undefined" data to my SQL server

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvvm, asp.net-core

I'm struggling to pass data from the front end of my project to the back end. What I'm trying to achieve here is to simply pass the month number and year back so that my backend methods may retrieve the data from the correct month and year. The month number and year number are being supplied by separate queries and by dropdown buttons.

I have 2 methods, one of the initial loading and one which fires after the user has changed one of the dropdown values.

Below are the various snippets of code. This first one is to set up the initial load of the chart. The code snippets are in this order (I'll put labels):
[AJAX, setDATA, SQL method with variables]

This is the initial loading data: 
First AJAX

```
                $.ajax({
                xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                url: areaUrl + "api/Change/IndividualMonthChange",
                success: data => {
                    self.isLoading(false);
                    self.data(data);
                    self.setPlotData(data);
                    self.isLoaded(true);
                },
                error: data => {
                    self.loadingError(true);
                }
            });
```

This is the setData section.

```
            self.setPlotData = (data: any) => {
            self.plotDataLabels.push('Significant', 'Normal', 'Minor', 'Standard', 'Urgent', 'Implementer');

            var dataItems = [];
            dataItems.push(
                { y: data.List[0].Significant, color: '#fea156' },
                { y: data.List[0].Normal, color: '#b191c3' },
                { y: data.List[0].Minor, color: '#83bfd1' },
                { y: data.List[0].Standard, color: '#72e76d' },
                { y: data.List[0].Urgent, color: '#fa5a5a' },
                { y: data.List[0].Implementer, color: '#f9da5b' }
            );
            self.plotData.push({ data: dataItems });
        }
```

And this is the SQL Server/C# query

```
        public ListResult IndividualMonthChange(int month = 7, int year = 2016)
    {
        var sql = "Select Count(Case When RQ.Req_Type_Composite_Ref = '5' Then 1 Else Null End) As[Significant], Count(Case When RQ.Req_Type_Composite_Ref = '124' Then 1 Else Null End) AS [Normal], Count(Case When RQ.Req_Type_Composite_Ref = '4' Then 1 Else Null End) AS [Minor], Count(Case When RQ.Req_Type_Composite_Ref = '6' Then 1 Else Null End) AS [Standard], Count(Case When RQ.Req_Type_Composite_Ref = '100' Then 1 Else Null End) AS [Urgent], Count(Case When RQ.Req_Type_Composite_Ref IN('5', '124', '4', '6', '100') Then 1 Else Null End) AS [TotalChanges],Count(Case When RQ.Req_Type_Composite_Ref NOT In(4, 5, 6, 100, 124) Then 1 Else Null End) AS [Implementer] " +
            "From VMWareSM_Test.dbo.RV_REQUEST As RQ " +
            "Where Req_Status_Ref Not In(3, 5, 6, 16, 21, 38, 43) ";

        var d = new DateTime();

        if (year >= 2000 && year <= d.Year)
        {
            sql += " And DATEPART(yyyy, RQ.Req_Impl_Start_Date) = @year AND DATEPART(MM, RQ.Req_Impl_Start_Date) = @month ";
        }

        SqlParameter[] sqlParams =
        {
            new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@month",
                Value = month,
                DbType = DbType.Int32,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            },
            new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@year",
                Value = year,
                DbType = DbType.Int32,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            }
        };

        var result = SqlHelper.ExecuteReadOnlyQuery(
            context: Db,
            sql: sql
            );

        return new ListResult(result, 1, result.Count, result.Count);
    }
```

This is ajax, setData and SQL Method that changes the data when one of the dropdown buttons are activated. Also included in this section is the index data for when the buttons fire off (once one of their values are changed). The data is pulled from the SQLServer/C# query above.

Note: the month and year numbers in the query method are just set as defaults. Its just for debug. However, Bonus is there is a way to have it set to the current month and current year. So far, my attempts keep telling that me the variables must be static at runtime or something of that nature so I can't use a reference.

```
            self.loadChangesData = (month: number, year: number) => {
            self.isChangesLoading(true);
            self.isChangesLoaded(false);

            $.ajax({
                xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                url: areaUrl + "api/Changes/IndividualMonthChange?year=" + year + "&month" + month,
                success: data => {
                    self.isChangesLoading(false);
                    self.data(data);
                    self.setChangesData(data);
                    self.isChangesLoaded(true);
                },
                error: data => {
                    self.loadingError(true);
                }
            });
        }
```

This ends up setting the data for the second chart. I'm not sure if it's the plotdata variable, but

```
        self.setChangesData = (data: any) => {
            while (self.plotData().length) {
                self.plotData().pop();
            }

            while (self.plotDataLabels().length) {
                self.plotDataLabels().pop();
            }

            self.plotDataLabels.push('Significant', 'Normal', 'Minor', 'Standard', 'Urgent', 'Implementer');

            var dataItems = [];
            dataItems.push(
                { y: data.List[0].Significant, color: '#fea156' },
                { y: data.List[0].Normal, color: '#b191c3' },
                { y: data.List[0].Minor, color: '#83bfd1' },
                { y: data.List[0].Standard, color: '#72e76d' },
                { y: data.List[0].Urgent, color: '#fa5a5a' },
                { y: data.List[0].Implementer, color: '#f9da5b' }
            );
            self.plotData.push({ data: dataItems });
        }
```

Here are the two methods that call for the chart to change when either of the dropdown buttons are changed. These might be the culprit because theses appear to be doing nothing. When checking the console, the error that appears states that both of these variables are "undefined".

Example: 
GET http://transistordev/VFire/api/Changes/IndividualMonthChange?year=function%20valueOf()%20{%20[native%20code]%20}?monthfunction%20valueOf()%20{%20[native%20code]%20}&_=1467746558438 404 (Not Found)

XHR http://transistordev/VFire/api/Changes/IndividualMonthChange?year=function%20valueOf()%20{%20[native%20code]%20}?monthfunction%20valueOf()%20{%20[native%20code]%20}&_=1467746558438

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with C#. But I remember having to add `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` to server side methods that I would access with AJAX, I believe they also needed to be `static`. More here. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: I have that code at the top of my controller file. I am having an issue with the month and year variables in the IndividualMonthChange method because both of my variables appear to draw an error at runtime indicating that they both need to declared as scalar variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So upon closer inspection, I realized I forgot to add a single line of code below. I didn't add the SQLparams code so the parameters can be sent through and I also forgot an '=' in the AJAX call.

Thanks!